# How do I use a column created in dplyr::do() within same call?

Tags: r, dplyr

`mutate` has the fantastic capability of being able to refer to columns one has created within the same call (e.g., `mutate(flights, gain = arr_delay - dep_delay, gain_per_hour = gain / (air_time / 60))`).

I'm trying to use the same thing working with `do()` . The following is just a throw away example -- I promise I have a good reason for wanting to do this:

```
data.frame(n=round(runif(1000,20,100),0)) %>%
group_by(n) %>%
do(
  x=mean(rnorm(.$n,10,1)),
  y=mean(rnorm(.$n,20,x))
)
```

Of course, I get the error `Error in rnorm(.$n, 20, x) : object 'x' not found`. If I try to use `.$x` I get `Error in rnorm(.$n, 20, .$x) : invalid arguments`. I haven't been able to find any documentation relating to this, and maybe it's just not possible -- but it seems like it should be.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you can't currently. File a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Without understand what you want to achieve, if you chain the do() into another do() then the result is just y.

```
data.frame(n=round(runif(1000,20,100),0)) %>%
group_by(n) %>% do(
  x=mean(rnorm(.$n,10,1))
) %>% do(
  y=mean(rnorm(.$n,20,.$x))
)
```

Comment: If you add `x=.$x` to the second `do` call, that about gets it. But it's not as pretty as how mutate works.